# Java Memory Model - Surprising Behaviors

Tags: java, java-memory-model

I am reading about Java Memory Model in JSR-133 and I cannot understand how this type of behavior is acceptable:
[image]

Can somebody please explain it?

Comment: that, and the fact that x is shared between the threads and the operations aren't atomic.

Comment: Both your answers are incorrect.

Comment: yes, I noticed. but then I don't understand the question, 8.1 explicitly describes the required, slightly obscure, but imaginable architecture

Comment: strictly according to the `JLS`, this is called a data race. Anything is possible for a data race, it would be rather helpful if you shows where exactly you have seen this example, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ONLY thing the CPU has to ensure is that the write to X within a thread does NOT affect the subsequent assignment to its associated RX memory location. It says nothing about where it gets the value it's going to write from.

So,
In thread 1, the CPU says

"Ohh, I need to read X", so begins a read operation.

It then says

"And I need to write to X", so then **QUEUES** the value in a write queue

Thread 2 does the same thing.

"Ohh, I need to read X" and begins the read.

"I need to write to X", and queues the write.

Now we have two waiting reads and two queued writes.

If the CPU architecture says that a read on one core may interrogate another core's write queue, then both cores can read each others outstanding writes to X. Hence you get the two values being pulled across cores, ultimately being assigned to the RX memory location from that thread.

When you place memory barriers in the instruction stream it prevents this type of over eager queued write reading.

Comment: `r1` and `r2` aren't "memory locations", or at least not ones that any other thread has a reference to.  In CPU terms, they're registers, which is why they have names like `r1`.  Semi-related: https://preshing.com/20120515/memory-reordering-caught-in-the-act/ but that's about StoreLoad reordering, rather than the LoadStore reordering that's necessary here to create the condition being asked about. (Except this is reordering operations on the same memory location, which is unusual.)

Comment: @PeterCordes The Java Virtual Machine is a stack machine, and as such does not have any (general purpose) registers. All op-codes are defined with relation to the values on the stack, hence I made the assumption that r1 and r2 are variables within code. Likewise, registers are memory, they are just located on the chip.

Comment: In JVM terms then, `r1` and `r2` in this litmus test would be data on the Java stack.  Yes, to see what you loaded from shared memory, you'll have to later copy those load results somewhere they can be collected (like local vars in memory), just like the situation with CPU registers for an assembly-language version of the litmus test.  (CPU registers are private to each core.  They're "memory" only in the sense that they store data and are physically made of SRAM, modulo register renaming; they don't have addresses in the usual sense and can't be addressed indirectly.)

Answer (score 1):

> **8.1 Surprising Behaviors Allowed by the Memory Model**
>
> Figure 12 shows a small but interesting example. The behavior r1 == 2
> and r2 == 1 is a legal behavior, although it may be difficult to see
> how it could occur. A compiler would not reorder the statements in
> each thread; this code must never result in r1 == 1 or r2 == 2.
> However, the behavior r1 == 2 and r2 == 1 might be allowed by a
> processor architecture that performs the writes early, but in a way
> that they were not visible to local reads that came before them in
> program order. This behavior, while surprising, is allowed by the Java
> memory model. To get this result in the memory model, we commit both
> writes followed by both reads.

Somehow the CPU has decided to write `x` earlier than to read `x`. All what this example says is, that this is valid behavior, more or less, this is an exception which is accepted as valid behavior.

Intel Itanium CPU could produce such behavior.

So instead of:

```
//Thread 1
int x = 0;
int r1 = x;
x = 1;

//Thread 2
int x = 0;
int r2 = x;
x = 2;
```

This happens:

```
//Thread 1
int x = 0;
x = 2; //from Thread 2
int r1 = x;

//Thread 2
int x = 0;
x = 1; //from Thread 1
int r2 = x;
```

And this is totally valid. (An accepted exception.)

Comment: The legal behavior in question is `r1 == 2` and `r2 == 1`. Your example shows `r1 == 1` and `r2 == 2` while "A compiler would not reorder the statements in each thread; [...]".

Comment: Thank you, I corrected it.

Comment: @paladin what allows CPU to re-arrenge [r1 = x, x = 5] to [x = 5, r1 = x]? would it destroy all programms? Thanks

Comment: It has nothing to do with "rights" but with hardware limits. Some CPU have to handle some code only in a certain way, that's why this exception exists. I agree with you that this exception will create software bugs if unhandled, that's why it's documented by the API and defined as valid. So the programmer has to take care of this nonsense ;-) I'm pretty sure usual mainstream CPU are not affected by this behavior.